# Error java.lang.RuntimeException when I want to create Destination Resource in glassfish

Tags: java, glassfish, jms

Full stack trace of error:

[2015-10-21T17:18:28.393+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context] [tid: _ThreadID=187 _ThreadName=admin-listener(9)] [timeMillis: 1445437108393] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException while attempting to process a 'beforeCreate' event for 'event247'.
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutElementBase.dispatchHandlers(LayoutElementBase.java:422)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutElementBase.dispatchHandlers(LayoutElementBase.java:394)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutComponent.beforeCreate(LayoutComponent.java:348)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutComponent.getChild(LayoutComponent.java:288)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.LayoutViewHandler.buildUIComponentTree(LayoutViewHandler.java:556)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.LayoutViewHandler.buildUIComponentTree(LayoutViewHandler.java:551)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.LayoutViewHandler.buildUIComponentTree(LayoutViewHandler.java:507)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.LayoutViewHandler.buildUIComponentTree(LayoutViewHandler.java:507)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.LayoutViewHandler.createView(LayoutViewHandler.java:255)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:256)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:123)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at com.sun.webui.jsf.util.UploadFilter.doFilter(UploadFilter.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doChainInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:678)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor142.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.handler.Handler.invoke(Handler.java:442)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutElementBase.dispatchHandlers(LayoutElementBase.java:420)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.handlers.UtilHandlers.mapPut(UtilHandlers.java:314)
    ... 51 more

Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: It's not possible for us to help you fix a `NullPointerException` without seeing the code.

Comment: But I don't have a code.I have queue in MOM(Open mq). I want to create a GlassFish JMS entry to map to the physical MOM queue.

Comment: And I don't have a tab Physical Destination in Java Message Service. Although in Open MQ I have 3 destinations. That is glassfish doesn't know about my destinations in open mq